# Discord.js bot (running on pm2) disconnecting randomly

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, discord.js, pm2

I have a Discord.js bot running on a VPS (Ubuntu 20.04) using pm2 (v5.1.2). I have 3 or 4 different bots all running the same way in their own containers but every now and again one of them will randomly go offline overnight. I have checked their logs in every instance and there is no fatal error seen in any of them, they simply just disconnect from Discord whilst their container keeps running.

Running `pm2 restart` fixes the problem but I would like a permanent fix if one exists. Does anyone have any suggestions for what might be the cause of this, or any ways to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Generally, that sort of thing is worked around with a keepalive/ping command – e.g. call some API every 1 minute or 5 minutes, and if there's no response (or a connection error), reconnect.

Comment: Was there any non-fatal error that occurred during the session, have you possibly been rate-limited? there are many reasons for such an issue to occur so please provide a bit more context.

Comment: A couple of non-fatal errors were logged however the bot continued to function as normal for several hours afterwards. The disconnects seem to happen at low activity hours so it being rate limited is very unlikely. My only thoughts are maybe it is disconnecting after a period of inactivity?